# How to remove and replace content in a div when using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this javascript to place text from an array into a `div`

```
function showTopic(j)   
{   
        document.getElementById("topicBox").innerHTML += 

        '<h2>'+ arrSubTopics[j].subCategoryName   +'</h2>

         '+ arrSubTopics[j].subCategoryInformation +' ';          
 }
```

This will only add to the `div`, but **I would like it to replace whatever is currently within the `div`**

Constructive criticism rather than downvotes please.

Comment: Not quite sure why it's down voted, it's a legitimate question and well worded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `=` instead of `+=`:

```
document.getElementById("topicBox").innerHTML = '<h2>' // the rest...
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `+=` with `=`:

```
document.getElementById("topicBox").innerHTML = ...
```

`+=` behaves as string concatenation, while you don't need it here.